# How can I decompose polynomials in a certain way?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I' ve learned that the following examples can be used to decompose a 
factor in this way

```
x^5 - 5 x + 12 == (x - a) (a^4 + a^3 x + a^2 x^2 + a x^3 + x^4 - 1)
 (x - a) (a^4 - (5 a^3)/8 + (7 a^2)/8 + 1/8 (5 a^2 - 12 a) + 
   1/8 (5 a^3 - 12 a^2) + ((5 a^4)/16 - a^3/8 + (7 a^2)/16 - 
      3/16 (5 a^2 - 12 a) + 1/16 (12 a^3 - 5 a^4) + 
      1/8 (12 a^2 - 5 a^3) - (9 a)/4) x^2 + ((5 a^4)/16 + a^3/4 + (
      5 a^2)/16 + 1/16 (12 a - 5 a^2) + 1/16 (12 a^3 - 5 a^4) + a/2 + 
      1/4 (12 - 5 a) - 3) x + a x^3 + a/4 + 1/4 (5 a - 12) + x^4 - 2)
```

How can I get Mathematica to decompose a polynomial function `f[x]` into `(x - a) g[x, a]`?

I want to know how to write a custom function like the built-in function `Factor`to achieve this goal.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but try `(x - a) PolynomialQuotient[poly, x - a, x]`

Comment: But the result of this situation is not consistent with my requirements:`(x - a) PolynomialQuotient[x^5 + 5 x - 12, x - a, x] // Expand`

Comment: I admit that the result doesn't look similar to your second example (I honestly don't understand its form), but it does satisfy your only explicitly stated requirement to decompose f[x] into (x - a) g[x, a]. Expand doesn't return the original polynomial, but it wouldn't return the original polynomials in any of your examples either. They're only equivalent when f[a]==0.

Comment: I don't understand your example; I can't see any reason why the three polynomials you show should be equal. Can can clarify your question?

Comment: I agree with @m_goldberg . The LHS and RHS are not equal. Is a supposed to be any arbitrary value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute the five roots of that quintic, and set `a` to any one of them.

```
qpoly = x^5 - 5 x + 12;
rt = First[x /. Solve[qpoly == 0, x]];
```

Then factor using that `a` as the extension.

```
fax = Factor[qpoly, Extension -> rt] /. rt -> a

(* Out[335]= 1/16 (-a + x) (8 - 5 a - a^2 - a^3 - 
   a^4 + (4 + 3 a - a^2 - a^3 - a^4) x + 4 x^2) (-4 - 2 a - 
   2 a^3 + (-4 + a + a^2 + a^3 + a^4) x + 4 x^2) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I know what is trying to be achieved. For illustrative purposes, I am going to use a smaller polynomial $x^2+3x+2=0$ which we know can be factored into $(x+1)(x+2)$. It is desired that we can rather factorise this polynomial into some form of $(x-a)g(x,a)$ and so we have 2 options.

Either $(x-a)(x-2a)$ or $(x-a)(x-\frac{1}{2}a)$ where $a=-1$ or $a=-2$ respectively. More simply $(x-a)(x+a+3)$. If this is the case, then

```
qpoly = x^5 - 3 x + 12;
roots = x /. Solve[qpoly == 0, x];
final = HoldForm[(x - a)] PolynomialQuotient[qpoly, x - a, x]
```

gives the output `(5 + a^4 + a^3 x + a^2 x^2 + a x^3 + x^4)(x-a)` note I get a 5 not a -1. I used Holdform to stop it going (-a+x)
Maybe someone more skilled than me can get the other forms.

The other issue I have, is when I replace a by one of the roots the output is not the original equation. Maybe someone can figure out why.